# Is it strange to let one user refresh the server cache when it affects all users?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I'm displaying a lot of data on a website that won't change often.  Because of this, I'm caching the data in HttpRuntime.Cache, which I understand to cache data for all users of the website.

However, I also want to offer the ability to force a refresh in case cache data becomes stale.  Since the data is cached for all users, this means that if a few people are using the site at once, it'll affect everyone.  Is this a common pattern?  It seems like strange behavior for a site to display, especially since one user could slow everyone down by constantly forcing cache refreshes.  It still doesn't make sense to do clientside caching since the data will be the same for all users.

Comment: I think it's incredibly common to cache items for a website and let them expire on their own with a time period. Then you are correct, at some point all users will see certain pieces of information be updated. Totally normal/common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching data visible to all users is extremely common, and is a good practice.  However giving users the ability to refresh the cache is pretty rare.  The better path would be to expire your cache when data is saved that would change the contents of a cached page.

Smart cache invalidation means that your users always see the freshest data, but they also get the benefits of your caching efforts.  Ideally, you're only expiring the pages affected by a change - not your entire cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be careless of you to allow a normal user to have the ability to invoke a "clear cache" operation.. your cache-able data should have some sort of dependency defined. See: [Cache Expiration Policies](http://www.neovolve.com/page/Cache-Expiration-Policies.aspx)